# Calling MSCRM OnPremise Discovery service

Tags: dynamics-crm

All,

I am having issues with calling DiscoveryService for MSCRM ONPremise

I downloaded DiscoveryWSDL file from MSCRM UNDER

Customizations > Developer Resources > Discovery Service WSDL

I uploaded that WSDL on SOAP UI, and when I execute SOAP call I get

"ERROR:Exception in request: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

Any thoughts?

SOAP CALL

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <soap:Body>
           <Execute >
                <Request xsi:type="RetrievePolicyRequest" />
           </Execute>
      </soap:Body>
```

Thanks,
Nitesh

Comment: It's a bit late here, but what exactly are you trying to do? What SOAP call did you execute?

Comment: I just added the SOAP call on the top.

Comment: if you browse the ws in your favourite browser, does it seem responsive? I haven't used soapUI to do anything with the webservices that I can remember.